# deploy VC++ win32 console project

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, console, installation

I have a win32 console project that have successfully compiled in 'Release' mode. I wonder if I can just deploy that stand-alone exe or should I have a setup program. If I do need to set up program, could someone help point to some helpful tutorial for setting up such a project. The project is compiled with 'Use MFC in a Static Library' setting.

Any help would be great.

Comment: It's user-friendly to provide an installer as it saves the user from having to deal with copying files around (and also makes it easy for them to remove your program if they want). InnoSetup is a good free installer.

Comment: don't see any c++ in this question.

Comment: You may need to bundle Visual C++ redistributable DLLs. That's best done with an installer. Otherwise link everything statically and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd better check which platform your project compile for. You can prepare both x86 and x64. Then, for each platform, find correspond runtime dlls, such as msvcr120d.dll, mfc110d.dll and distribute them with your standalone exe. To find all necessary dlls, you can execute your standalone exe on another clean computer, and lost file name will be on message. An easy way is to use Visual C++ Redistributable, but it is a little bit large.

Comment: Trial and error is not how to enumerate dependencies.

Comment: In addition to David's comment, the missing dependency is usually not spelled out in the error message. [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kche8ah.aspx) explains how to properly go about this.